# NullPointerException on existing socket

Tags: java, sockets, nullpointerexception

Disclaimer: Before anyone marks this a duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), I know what a NullPointerException is and how to fix it. This concrete NullPointer, for some reason after a few hours I can't fix.

So, I have a simple socket class where I create my socket and send two Hello as a test:

```
package network.outgoing;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;


public class MySocket extends Thread{
    private Socket socketServer;
    private DataOutputStream doStream;
    private DataInputStream diStream;
    private final int PORT;

    public MySocket(int port) {
        this.PORT = port;
    }


    public void run() {
        InetAddress iAddress;
        try {
            iAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            String ip = iAddress.getHostAddress();

            socketServer = new Socket(ip, PORT);
            doStream = new DataOutputStream(socketServer.getOutputStream());
            diStream = new DataInputStream(socketServer.getInputStream());
            doStream.writeUTF("Hello, I'm " + Node.name);
            doStream.writeUTF("Hello 2");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void notifyData(String operation, String name) {
        try {
            doStream.writeUTF("OPERATION"); //NullPointerException
            doStream.writeUTF(operation);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I need several instances of this class, so in my main controller I have an array where I store them:

```
private final ArrayList<MySocket> socketListA;
```

which is initialized in the constructor:

```
socketListA = new ArrayList<>(); // only place where a new is called on socketListA
setSockets(ports, myPort);
```

in the `setSockets` method (a simplified version removing other innecessary stuff):

```
for (int port : ports) {
    MySocket mySocket = new MySocket(port); // only place where a new is called on MySocket
    mySocket.start();
    socketListA.add(mySocket);
}
```

Creating and starting the `MySocket` thread sends correctly the two test Hello from the `run` method, but accessing it from the array as such:

```
socketListA.get(random.nextInt(socketListA.size() - 1)).notifyData(line, name);
```

gives null pointer on the `doStream` inside the `notifyData` method.

I tested several things:

- Not using the arrayList: `setSocket` returning directly a single instance of `MySocket` and trying a `doStream` (set to public for this test) from the returned instace, but it's null:
- Checked if the instance in the arrayList, is the same as the one created and stored in it (with both hash and equals) and yes, they are the same (not accessing an invalid or different instance when calling `notifyData`). Same check was done in the previous point for the returned instance of `MySocket`
- Created (again) a `doStream` on the `notifyData` method. This works, but it shouldn't be necessary as `doStream` should have a value.

Note: The `socketListA` arrayList is created only once, and the `MySocket` instance is created also once.

Why is the `doStream` in `notifyData` null, if it has been created in the `run` method and the instance of the class is the same?

Comment: *Why is the doStream in notifyData null* Obviously because it is called before it is initialized

Comment: Meaning I make a call to mySocket before the run method in the other thread is completed?

Comment: Yes, as it is explained in duplicated question

Comment: Thread.start doesn't call Thread.run, it takes some time to setup the thread and call run on it, you should do some synchronisation

Comment: Correct. Swapping start for run made it. I thought of this, but I discarded it as my code is a bit more complex than the example here. I make some actions before any call to `notifyData` is made, and thought it had time to do the start. I was wrong.